# UIButton with highlighted bottom border

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to implement custom buttons something like in the picture, when clicking on button it highlight with text color and bottom border. could anyone help me with that?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image you've shown is probably a UISegmentedControl. That's how you tap something so that it stays selected (and other choices are deselected). It's easy to customize a segmented control so that the background image is different when a segment is selected vs. when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes matt is right, here's a third party segment control which I have used in one of my app. It's nice and same as your requirement. Oh yes, it's written in Obj-C only. https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

```
HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"Search",@"Broadcast"]];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 60);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(id)sender {
    //handle segment selection
}
```

Comment: @MayankPatel, I guess sample code isn't required. Anyways, have fulfilled with sample code too. :)